# Python : Remove duplicate elements in lists and sublists; and remove full sublist if duplicate

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there is any function or way to achieve this recursively in python 2.7 ?

```
Input : ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]
Output : ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]
```

Remove duplicate 'P' in sublist1 as duplicate

```
Input : ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P'], ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P']]
Output : ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]
```

Remove duplicate 'P' in sublist1 as duplicate as well remove sublist3 as duplicate of sublist1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to create a custom `remove duplicate` function inorder to preserve order of sublists.Try this:

```
def rem_dup(lis):
    y, s = [], set()
    for t in lis:
        w = tuple(sorted(t)) if isinstance(t, list) else t
        if not w in s:
            y.append(t)
            s.add(w)
    return y

inp = ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P'], ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P']]

out = [rem_dup(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in rem_dup(inp)] 

>>>out
['and', ['or', 'P', '-R'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` and a generator expression to convert the inner list to tuple that is a immutable object and then apply the `set` on it :

```
>>> a=['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P'], ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P']]
>>> set(tuple(p) if isinstance(p,set) else p for p in (set(i) if isinstance(i,list) or isinstance(i,tuple) else i for i in a))
set(['and', ('P', 'or', '-R'), ('P', '-Q', 'or', '-R')])
```

Comment: The output still contains duplicate 'P'. Also can we do anything to preserve order of sublists or items

Comment: Your output still contains duplicate 'P'. Also we I tried your logic and the order of sublists change. Can we do anything to preserve order of sublists or items

Comment: Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: @SandeepKulkarni sorry i miss that simple point! i edit the code ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `OrderedDict` which will remove dups and keep order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
inp= ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]

out = [OrderedDict.fromkeys(sub).keys() if isinstance(sub, list) else sub for sub in inp]
print(out)
['and', ['or', 'P', '-R'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P']]
```

To remove duplicate sublists, cast the lists as tuples and use fromkeys again:

```
inp = ['and', ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P'], ['or', '-Q', '-R', 'P'], ['or', 'P', '-R', 'P']]
out = OrderedDict.fromkeys(tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sub).keys()) if isinstance(sub, list) else sub for sub in inp)

print(out.keys())
['and', ('or', 'P', '-R'), ('or', '-Q', '-R', 'P')]
```

If you want lists again just cast and use iterkeys for python2:

```
out = OrderedDict.fromkeys(tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sub).iterkeys()) if isinstance(sub, list) else sub for sub in inp)
print([list(ele) if isinstance(ele, tuple) else ele for ele  in out.iterkeys()])
```